# How to serialize a class implementing a interface with gson?

Tags: kotlin, serialization, gson

There is a interface A:

```
interface A {
    val name: String
}
```

Also there is one class B implementing this interface:

```
class B() : A {
    val implementedName: String = "Test"

    override val name: String
        get() = implementedName
}
```

Then i try to serialize this class B:

```
val b: A = B()
Gson().toJson(b)
```

And geht the following output:

```
// Output
{"implementedName":"Test"}
```

I realize the gson to type erasure can't infere the type of the variable b, but what I want to see is gson serializing the interface fields:

```
// Output
{"name":"Test"}
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Gson can't do that. Using SerializedName annotation Android Studio highlights that it is not possible to do this. This annotation is not applicable to target 'member property without backing field or delegate. But implementing it this way should work.

```
interface A {
    val name: String
}

class B() : A {
    @SerializedName("your_name")
    override val name: String = "Test"
}
```

Then using Gson().toJson(b) the output should be:

```
{"your_name": "Test"}
```

Comment: This isn't applicable for me I have different classes implementing the interface A and the all should be able implement the name field however the want. But every class of them when serialized should have the same json structure.

Comment: @natschz can't you use an abstract class instead of an interface?

Comment: So for me it isn't that simple its a more complexe object also with nested objects which have the same issue where they implement a interface. I'm just wondering if it is really necessary to have to implement this myself mapping the object. This would either mean mapping the object completely myself or create a other class which implements the interfaces and then maps the origina/implemented class to that interface.